# AlarmManager deleted - force close app

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm looking for a solution for days now. There might not even be a solution.

What happens is the following:
I got an application which schedules alarms for users, for the user to get out of bed. It's really important that the alarms "always" go off.

To be able to let the alarms go off I make use of an AlarmManager. This schedules intents to be executed on scheduled times. This works fine when the Application is open or closed with the back/home button.

When I close the app with Force Close option, the Alarm Manager alarms get cleared from the system and they will not go off.

I have tried the following things already:

- START_STICKY Service
- DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler - Won't work, because there isn't an exception caught for force closing the app.
- Broadcast Receiver - The issue is with the alarms being deleted.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced the same issue with the AlarmManager class and if you found a solution or alternative to fix this problem.

p.s. I'm creating the Alarm Manager alarms like this:

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckAlarmService.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            int daysTillAlarm = AlarmHelper.calculateDaysTillAlarm(alarm);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**EDIT:**

To try and see if I wasn't the only one with the issue, I downloaded some well used alarm clocks. They all seem to have the same behavior as I do. For now I'll leave it be. They're also well rated.

Still if you might have the solution to this problem I'd like to know!

Comment: Im wodering about the same issue. Its becoming problematic since there is a bug in kitkat that doesnt restart  a service even if you start sticky it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing you code:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            1, myIntent, 0);
```

Also try adding:

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

before:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I tried it, but I thought it wouldnt work and it didnt work. These FLAGS are to say what I want to do with the PendingIntent. (update, create new, cancel exist then create). Thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: @ThijsLimmen please check edited answer. Install a fresh copy of you app and then try

Comment: This also didn't work. I'm wondering. Did you get this working on any of your apps? Or maybe you think of Force closing, closing in a different way. For example I have an Samsung Galaxy S2. When the App is open I long press the home button. Then I'll see the process menu. There I click "End".  This force closes the applications. Only from this point the Alarm Manager is cleared. Hiding/closing in any other way works.

Comment: @ThijsLimmen What error you get in you logcat, please post it

Comment: No errors. The Alarm Managers I set are cleared, when force closed. I found several explanations for it happening. One you see below your answer. It's probably something to prevent people from making viruses.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view (as Android user) this is right behavior. Imagine application which has bug leading to crash (with crash dialog), and this application scheduled some action to be started every minute. What can you do with crash dialog appearing every minute?

So I hope there is no direct answer to your question (like "just call this method").
As always, there are ugly ways - like starting several processes which track all others and restart if needed, but then your application starts to look like virus...

Comment: You're right. I read these things many times. Still I'm looking for a solution. This nasty way might just be the way I'm required to do, to get the behavior I want, but maybe someone has a better solution. Thanks for the answer!